# Text centering in all browsers but Internet Explorer (Link included)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having trouble getting the text to center inside of a list item. This seems to only be happening in internet explorer and I just can't figure out why... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Image Example:**

[image: issue]
https://img.skitch.com/20110301-p9hg9ihgimd6srraa9cirnqcdp.jpg

Site (see problem area at bottom): http://www.levelsetsolutions.com/optimize/swa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is entering in quirks mode. You can avoid that using a doctype like for example:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Doh' This totally just fixed it... I can't tell you how much trouble that one line just saved me. Thanks so much :)

Comment: I love it when the answer is this, it's so easy.

Answer (score 0):

The width you set on the A tags is too small.

I'd recommend moving all the CSS properties having to do with dimensions (height, width, margin, padding, etc.) to the LI tag and adding a BR tag between each word in the list items. This is the only way to guarantee the line-break will happen where you want it to.